# A simple question about completely positive linear maps

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be the C*-algebra and $M_{n}(A)$ be the C*-algebra of $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $A$. We use $(a_{ij})$ to denote the element of $M_{n}(A)$.

My question is:

**For every $a\in A$, can we verifies that$(a_{i}^{*}a^{*}aa_{j})\leq||a^{*}a||(a_{i}^{*}a_{j})$. Here, we fix $\{a_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}\in A$.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $M_n(\mathcal{A})$ is a $C^*$-algebra, so we have
$$
A\leq B\implies C^*AC\leq C^*BC
$$
for all $A,B,C\in M_n(\mathcal{A})$. Since $A\leq \Vert A\Vert 1_{M_n(\mathcal{A})}$ for all $A\in M_n(\mathcal{A})_+$ we get
$$
C^*AC\leq \Vert A\Vert C^*C
$$
Now consider
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
a^*a & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
0 & a^*a & \ldots & 0\\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & a^*a\\
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
C=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & \ldots & a_n\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
\ldots & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$